# Posting (Uploading) an image to Instagram using Selenium not using an API

Tags: python, json, selenium, upload

Background:

I've been trying to solve this for a while now. I'm using Selenium (chrome webdriver) to access the mobile version of Instagram from the desktop. My goal is to create a script to automate posting an image to an account. Using Python I have automated everything up to the part where I need to select the file.

Issue:

Once I click the create new post button the gui file selector opens and I cannot figure out how to interact with it to select the file.

Tried:

post_btn.send_keys(r'/Path/To/image.jpg')

post_btn.send_keys('/Path/To/image.jpg')

The trouble, I think, with this method is there is not input field to send the string to.

I read some other posts about using autoit and that working, but I'm on a Mac.

Here's the span the post button lives in:

```
<span class="glyphsSpriteNew_post__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7" aria-label="New Post"></span>
```

Question:

Is there a way to 'open' (upload) a file through a file selector gui using python?
Better, can I bypass opening the file selector at all?

Thanks!

Edit:

I think what's stopping me from solving this is that I don't understand how the data is being sent and received. Since it's not an html input does that mean it is JSON? How do I figure out how the data (image) is being sent to the next page (https://www.instagram.com/create/style/)?

Comment: How did you accessed Mobile Version of Instagram? I tried `chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=411,411")` but it opens the desktop version

Answer (score 6):

IDK if this will be useful to you because it has been so long.But to anyone who needs it here is the full tutorial,

Imports:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import autoit
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

So First you need a emulator.
The best method that I found was using chromedriver.exe which you already need if you are using chrome as the browser. So to make the emulator you need this bit of code for the driver:

```
mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19" }
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
```

Then you  login:

```
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("Your Username")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("Your Password") 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[7]/button""").click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + username)
```

Name your file (It needs to be full name):

```
ImagePath = 'Your File Location'
```

final step is this:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element( driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]""")).click().perform()
handle = "[CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]"
autoit.win_wait(handle, 3)
autoit.control_set_text(handle, "Edit1", dir_path)
autoit.control_click(handle, "Button1")

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="react-root"]/section/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/button""").click()

time.sleep(2)

txt = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_472V_')
txt.send_keys('')
txt = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_472V_')
txt.send_keys('test') # Descrition
txt.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="react-root"]/section/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/button""").click()
```

All this does is go the the upload page and use autoit to navigate through windows to select a file and choose. Then just adds a description and shares the post.

Comment: one note on this : autoit is only for windows os.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this at my end and I can clearly see that there is no way to bypass file selector. That being said, you need to use external tool to automate file selector.  In my experience [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) could be best fit for this job.

Comment: Yea, I built the script using SikuliX last night after posting this, but it feels super hackish, actually way worse than hackish. I think it made me a bit nauseous :^P. I feel like there has to be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: @ShaneCheek Is sikuli still there? the website is not accessible :(

Answer (score 0):

I found this somewhere and it works fine in python.
import pyautogui
pyautogui.write('D:\opt\FitnessStudio\picofme.jpg')
pyautogui.press('enter')

Answer (score 0):

```
# ------------ Imports --------------- 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random

# ------------ Def Random --------------
def sleepTime(start):
    _sleep = (random.randint(start, 20))
    time.sleep(_sleep)

#  ---------------- WebDriver -----------------
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
driver.email = '*instaID*'
driver.password = '*instapswd*'
driver.username = '*instapageusernameyouwanttofollow*'
sleepTime(5)
try:
    emailInput=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'username']")
    passwordInput=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'password']")
except (NoSuchElementException, ElementNotVisibleException) as exceptions:
    pass
emailInput.send_keys(driver.email)
passwordInput.send_keys(driver.password)
passwordInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleepTime(7)

# ---pop up handle---
NotNow=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text() = 'Not Now']").click()
sleepTime(5)
# ---------- Going to folower list ----------
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + driver.username + '/')
sleepTime(7)
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + driver.username + '/followers/')
Followers=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='-nal3 ']").click()
sleepTime(7)
# -------------------------------------------
#find all li elements in list
fBody  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']")
scroll = 0
for j in (1,(random.randint(4, 20))):
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
    sleepTime(10)
# for k in (1,4):
#     driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollDown = arguments[0].scrollDown + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
#     time.sleep(10)

count = 0
while scroll < 500: # scroll 500 times
    sleepTime(10)
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
    for i in (0,(random.randint(5, 20))):
        try:
            Follow=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text() = 'Follow']")
            Follow.click()
            print(count)
            count = count + 1
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)                
            time.sleep(10)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
    sleepTime(8)
    # driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,100)")
    scroll += 1
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
    sleepTime(4)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically we have to upload a media to [instagram.com](https://www.instagram.com/)

you can't upload media directly to instagram without invoking `New Post` button and the `New Post` button contains a **Form** with input field

`<form class="_abpf" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" role="presentation"><input accept="image/jpeg" class="_ac69" type="file"></form>`

this from will only work when we invoke `New Post` button .

So this line `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@aria-label="New post"]').click()` will activate `New Post` button

after that

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="_abpf"]/input').send_keys('path to media')` this will upload media from local storage.

We have to perform this trivial step because `New post` button is using `::before` and `::after` concept of css

[Screenshot of inspected element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOMEz.png) - Here i've added screenshot of `::before` and `::after` in source code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC




opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_31 \
like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) \
CriOS/80.0.3987.95 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1") #iphone user-agent to spoof instagram
opts.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chrome _ driver _ path',chrome_options=opts)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

# wait for element 
# searching "Log In" first because we are using mobile user-agent
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Log In')]")))

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'Log In')]").click()
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"username").send_keys("your username")
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"password").send_keys("your password") 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'Log In')]").click()



#Main post logic
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@aria-label="New post"]')))

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@aria-label="New post"]').click()


driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="_abpf"]/input').send_keys('path to media')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(),"Next")]')))

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(),"Next")]').click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="_abrw"]/textarea').send_keys("Your Comment")
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(),"Share")]').is_displayed()
if button:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(),"Share")]').click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Could you explain us how this code works and what it does?

Comment: Is there a way hiding GUI browser after clicking new posts? Like you said it is still not activated if yo do not click and you cannot send input. But after click it opens a window GUI that you have to select the image. I used the code in headless mode so i do not want to see any GUI window. Can you help ?

Comment: I think we can handle it via process id (in linux). Like using `ps aux | grep (browser)`. Idea is to check the processes of browser before clicking on **new post** and checking after the media is uploaded, so that we can able to get the details of new process created for **GUI window**. Then we can kill it with `sudo kill -9 (ps id)`. This is just a rough idea. Try to apply it and keep me in the loop.