# Upload an image to Instagram on Windows without API

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, instagram

This is a knowledge sharing inspired by : [Posting (Uploading) an image to Instagram using Selenium not using an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864531/posting-uploading-an-image-to-instagram-using-selenium-not-using-an-api/68148847#68148847)

Most of the answer from internet only has Python version, so I am here to publish a JavaScript version in node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This solution only works under Windows OS.**

Below code reads photos with `.jpg` format from upload folder and post one by one with caption.

1. Download the autoit module from :

> https://github.com/xhawk18/node-autoit/issues/15

2. Update `package.json` with below dependencies:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-beta.4",
    "autoit": "file:autoit-2.0.1.tgz"   
},
```

3. Run `npm install`
4. Run the actual code :

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { Builder, By, Key } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const au = require('autoit');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

const instagramUrl = 'https://www.instagram.com/';
const account = 'YOUR_INSTAGRAM_ACCOUNT';
const password = 'YOUR_INSTAGRAM_PASSWORD';
const instagramLoginUrl = instagramUrl + 'accounts/login/';
const instagramAccountUrl = instagramUrl + account;

const waitTime = 2000;
const uploadFolder = 'uploadFolderName'
const mobileDeviceName = 'iPhone X';
const loginAlert = '//*[@id="slfErrorAlert"]';
const newPostButton = '//div[@data-testid="new-post-button"]';
const nextButton = '//button[text()="Next"]';
const captionTextArea = '//textarea[@aria-label="Write a caption…"]';
const shareButton = '//button[text()="Share"]';

let readFileNames = () => {
 let filenames = [];
 fs.readdirSync(uploadFolder).forEach(file => {
   let filename = file.split('.');
   if (filename[1] == 'jpg') {
     filenames.push(file);
   }
 })
 return filenames;
}

let filenames = readFileNames();

(async function example() {
 let driver = await new Builder()
   .forBrowser('chrome')
   .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options()
     .setMobileEmulation({ deviceName: mobileDeviceName }))
   .build();
 try {
   // Go to Login page 
   await driver.get(instagramLoginUrl);
   await driver.sleep(waitTime);
   // Login
   await driver.findElement(By.name('username')).sendKeys(account);
   await driver.findElement(By.name('password')).sendKeys(password, Key.RETURN);
   await driver.sleep(waitTime);
   // Redirect to Profile Home Page
   await driver.get(instagramAccountUrl);
   await driver.sleep(waitTime);
   //Read Local Photos
   for (let file of filenames) {
     //Create New Post
     await driver.findElement(By.xpath(newPostButton)).click();
     await driver.sleep(waitTime);
     let imagePath = `${__dirname}\\${uploadFolder}\\${file}`;
     console.log(imagePath);
     // Handle Windows Upload Photo Dialog
     let handle = "[TITLE:Open]";
     au.Init();
     au.WinWait(handle);
     au.Send(imagePath);
     au.ControlClick(handle, "", "Button1");
     await driver.sleep(waitTime);
     // Hit Next
     await driver.findElement(By.xpath(nextButton)).click();
     await driver.sleep(waitTime);
     // Fill The Captions
     await driver.findElement(By.xpath(captionTextArea)).sendKeys("Your caption");
     await driver.sleep(waitTime);
     // Share New Post
     await driver.findElement(By.xpath(shareButton)).click();
     await driver.sleep(waitTime);
     // Back To Home Page
     await driver.get(instagramAccountUrl);
   }
 }
 catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
 }
 finally {
   await driver.quit();
 }
})();
```