# Uploading a picture on Instagram using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to upload a image + text with Selenium, I already saw this solution
[Posting (Uploading) an image to Instagram using Selenium not using an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864531/posting-uploading-an-image-to-instagram-using-selenium-not-using-an-api)

but the problem is, that AutoIt is only running on Windows and I want to put the Bot on a linux server...

I can get anything done, until the gui file selector opens, because idk how to interact with it.

```
import selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#define webdriver and emulate IPhone X
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "iPhone X" }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

class Instagram:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.counter  = 0

    def login(self):
        #accept cookies and press login button
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[1]")))
        element.click()
        sleep(1)
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]")))
        element.click()
        #type in username and password
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/label/input")))
        element.send_keys(self.username)
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[4]/div/label/input")))
        element.send_keys(self.password)
        #click login button
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[6]/button")))
        element.click()
        #press dont safe information button
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/main/div/div/div/button")))
        element.click()
        #press dont add instagram to favoruite sides
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")))
        element.click()
        #scroll down, so the activate notification button appears
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,2000)", "")
        #press false on activate notifiation
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")))
        element.click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/button/span")))
        element.click()

    def goToStart(self):
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

    def likeByHashtag(self,hashtags,amount):
        #open instagram site with the tag
        for hashtag in hashtags:
            driver.implicitly_wait(60)
            driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + hashtag)
            for i in range(0,amount+1):
                # find all pictures and put into list
                elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_9AhH0")
                #take one element out of list
                element = elements[i]
                #open it
                element.click()
                element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/main/div/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div/span")))
                element.click()
                sleep(6)
                #go back
                driver.back()

    def upload(self, imgage, text):
        self.image = image
        self.text = text


rn = Instagram("zzz", "zzz")
rn.login()
#rn.likeByHashtag(["hello"],10)
sleep(120)

#quit
driver.quit()
driver.close()
```

Would be cool, if you could help me :)

Comment: Page url if public, yes even button HTML will work

Comment: Sure, https://www.instagram.com/

I will ad some other things now

Comment: How do I navigate to reach there where we have upload button ?

Comment: Just emulate a phone and click the little button in the middle...

I think, thats the only way^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there is a input tag with type as a file.

```
input[type='file']
```

if we see any `css` with matching above css selector, then we can use send_keys to send the file, we do not need auto it or any other tool. it would work in `windows/unix/mac` etc.

**Code :**

```
def upload(self, imgage, text):
    upload_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']")
    time.sleep(2)
    upload_btn.send_keys('full path of the file which is to be uploaded')
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a good idea!
 Could you please tell me how to put in the file and add the description?

Comment: pass the full file path here `'full path of the file which is to be uploaded'` see above I have updated the code.

Answer (score -1):

Updated XPATH for file upload to Instagram

```
upload=browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/input")
```